# How to turn a .bmp or a .xlsx into a 2D array

Tags: java, python, c++, excel, bmp

I have a .bmp file and a matrix representation of its greyscale values in a .xlsx file. Originally I thought I would just take the values from the .xlsx file and hard code it into an array, but I just opened it up and there are way too many values to ever type in by hand. I'm looking for help to recreate these 2d array values by just reading in either the .bmp or .xlsx file, whichever is easier. I initially thought of writing this program in C++, but I don't mind getting a Python or Java solution. I have never done this before, so I'm looking for a noob-friendly solution

Comment: You can use the `ImageIO` class in Java to read many image formats.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way in C++ might be using a library such as [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/)

Something like the following:

```
load("yourFile.xlsx");
Sheet* sheet = getSheet(0); // Index of sheet you want

for(int i=sheet->firstRow(); i<sheet->lastRow(); i++)
{
  for(int j=sheet->firstCol(); i<sheet->lastCol(); j++)
  {
    cout << readStr(i, j) << endl; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python

```
from scipy.ndimage import imread 

image = imread('image.bmp')
```

If you want to do image manipulation,  have a look into the scikit-image and pillow libraries.

Comment: If you could explain how to get scipy, this might be perfect. I tried following along with their website, but I have no idea what I'm doing (OS X)

Comment: The easiest way might be to install the Anaconda python distribution or using homebrew.

Comment: https://www.continuum.io/downloads